# getting import error when setting up virtual environment in python

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm trying to set up a virtual environment to work with python, I installed python and the packages I needed and here's how the folder looks

```
python3_9_7 % ls
bin     include     lib     pyvenv.cfg  share
```

when I run Ipython in terminal window I get a traceback error and I understand very little as I'm just starting now so any help on how to fix this is greatly appreciated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/terminal/embed.py", line 15, in <module>
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 73, in <module>
    from IPython.core.history import HistoryManager
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/history.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/emanuelatiberi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/emanuelatiberi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/emanuelatiberi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/emanuelatiberi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-39-darwin.so
(base) (python3_9_7) emanuelatiberi@192 python3_9_7 % export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib        
(base) (python3_9_7) emanuelatiberi@192 python3_9_7 % ipython
dyld: warning, DYLD_ setting caused circular dependency in /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
dyld: Symbol not found: __DefaultRuneLocale
  Referenced from: /Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/bin/python3
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/emanuelatiberi/Desktop/python3_9_7/bin/python3
zsh: abort      ipython
```